# How to add page links for multiple pages in Bing search api in php

Tags: php, search-engine, bing-api

I used the following code to include bing API in my web page. How can I add paging to this web search ?

Currently it shows only 1st 50 results and does not show the page links to other results. Also, how do I limit the results in one page to 20 ?

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
   {
    $acctKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $rootUri = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search';
    $query = $_POST['searchText'];
    $serviceOp ='Web';
    $market ='en-us';
    $query = urlencode("'$query'");
    $requestUri = "$rootUri/$serviceOp?\$format=json&Query=$query";
    $auth = base64_encode("$acctKey:$acctKey");
    $data = array(  
        'http' => array(
                    'request_fulluri' => true,
                    'ignore_errors' => true,
                    'header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"
                    )
        );
    $context = stream_context_create($data);
    $response = file_get_contents($requestUri, 0, $context);
    $response=json_decode($response);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo("<ol>");
    foreach($response->d->results as $value)
    {
    $Ur = $value->Url;
    echo '<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="{$Ur}"> '.$Ur. '
    </a><br><p>';
    echo($value->Description .'</li> </p>');

    }
    echo("</ol>"); 
    echo "</pre>";
    }

?>
```